# Jasper Report in Wordpress.

Tags: php, wordpress, jasper-reports

I am trying to integrate jasper report in WordPress using 'phpjasperxml'.
The database connection is successful but generated pdf is always blank.

```
<?php
    include_once('class/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
    include_once("class/PHPJasperXML.inc.php");
    include_once ('setting.php');

    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

    $PHPJasperXML = new PHPJasperXML();
    //$PHPJasperXML->debugsql=true;
    $PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter=array("quot_no"=>149);
    $PHPJasperXML->load_xml_file("mquotation.jrxml");
    $PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray($server,$user,$pass,$db);
    $PHPJasperXML->outpage("I");    //page output method I:standard output  D:Download file

?>
```

I don't know how to debug this. also how to pass parameter to report. I have created the report in iReport and it is working fine.

Comment: Just in case others would find it useful, now there is a Wordpress plugin available, which allows embedding JasperReports reports and visualizations using the JasperReports IO microservice as backend.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/jasperreports-io/

Answer (score 1):

First, I would create an empty report with only static text on it and try to get it to work.

Then, I would add parameters. If the report is empty, it might be because the parameters are not delivered. Your parameter description looks fine. In the [examples](https://github.com/BBFMedia/PHPJasperXML/blob/master/sample8.php) it is used the same way:

```
$PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter=array("parameter1"=>1);
```

I only saw a difference between your file usage and the usage in the example:

```
$xml =  simplexml_load_file("sample8.jrxml");
[...] 
$PHPJasperXML->xml_dismantle($xml);
$PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray($server,$user,$pass,$db);
```

*NOTE:* If you are not successful with this, you might consider using [JasperPHP](https://github.com/cossou/JasperPHP) if compatible.

Comment: Thank you. will try this. I had to do this in some other way.